# pd.read_excel("file.xlsx") does not create 'DataFrame' but 'OrderedDict'

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am currently working on a project using pandas for data science. I work with Spyder as IDE. However, after having installed and tested VSCode I am encountering a problem with my code as it seems that pandas is not working as before.

I am creating a DataFrame from an Excel file and use only a sample of it at the moment (for testing purposes).

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("Input.xlsx", sheet_name=None)
sample = data.sample(n=20, random_state=1).reset_index()
```

However, my data variable is now of type 'OrderedDict' instead of a 'DataFrame'. Thus, also the sample function does not work:

```
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'sample'
```

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall pandas but it does not help. By the way, it does not work in either of the IDEs.

The problem occured just after I installed VSCode and tried to run the code in there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sheet_name=None` indicates you **want** a dictionary of dataframes, each item in the dictionary representing a different worksheet.

Do not specify `sheet_name` if there is only a single worksheet in your workbook.

Alternatively, if you have multiple worksheets and you only want to read in one, specify it explicitly, e.g. `sheet_name='my_sheet_name'`.

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) lays out the options:

```
  Defaults to 0   |                        1st sheet as a DataFrame
              1   |                        2nd sheet as a DataFrame
       "Sheet1"   |                        1st sheet as a DataFrame
 [0,1,"Sheet5"]   |    1st, 2nd & 5th sheet as a dict of DataFrames
           None   |        All sheets as a dictionary of DataFrames
```

Comment: Oh wow... It was that easy. Thanks a lot! Seems that I have worked with an older version of pandas before!

Comment: It's easy to get confused about this so thank you for the classification.